# Casting an EditText as a TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

This is a question on performance, not on capability.

When I get a View from findViewById(...), and it's an EditText, but I don't need anything specific to EditText, should I cast the View to TextView or to EditText? TextView is a closer subclass to View, but EditText is what the View actually is.

Comment: why would you want to do that ?

Comment: Interesting question! In reality I don't think you'll see any performance benefits and I have a feeling there is no difference in "how far away" a subclass is as to casting performance but maybe someone else will confirm.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, yes you can cast the edittext as textview. But I dont think there is any must-to-follow rule. You can perform operations either by casting to an edittext or a textview.

As you dont need the functionalities of edittext you can surely cast to textview

Answer (score 0):

I can see no problem doing that. If you dont have any `EditText` specific task then go ahead and cast it to `TextView`.

P.S.:- I personally do that always.. :D

Answer (score 0):

You should cast it to EditText because otherwise it will through exception and your application will be crashed. And BTW if you are doing such things in your code I don't think you are following good practices. So don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think, for me clarity is more important than any kind of optimization you can think of making in your application. If you have an EditText then leave it as such, otherwise you are only adding confusion to the code.

Comment: I think you are mistaken, I haven't said anything about throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

At the end the object already exists, and it is an EditText, so you will be accessing an EditText, no matter what are you casting it. You are only casting it in order to use it's methods in code, but the object instance doesn't change. So regarding to the inheritance, for example, if the EditText has overriden a method of the TextView, if you cast the object to a TextView and use it, you will still be using the EditText method.

Anyway, the virtual machine should cache the results of method resolution, so it wil be no impact in further use.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about premature optimizations.  Is this actually a bottleneck in your code?  It shouldn't be.  Something like this is totally negligible.  It shouldn't have any noticeable effect on performance because it's still the same underlying object, just the type is being handled differently.

edit: Also, you may not need the EditText features now, but in the future you may.  Just leave it as an EditText to save yourself a maintenance headache in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that there IS benefit in casting an EditText to a TextView in java code.

Doing so can reduce the amount of imports in your code, which can (drastically) reduce the size of your compiled APK.

EditTexts and Buttons can more often than not be referenced as TextViews in code (Buttons could also just be a View). Almost any kind of ViewGroup can be referenced as just ViewGroup. AbsListView instead of ListView (API 11+). AbsSpinner instead of Spinner. Just to name a few easy ones. Doing so has reduced some of my apk sizes by 20-30%.

Answer (score -1):

you can miss the cast. `findViewById` returns a `View` object. If you don't need anything specific, work with it as `View` object

**EDIT:**

since we are talking about performance, here is a quick test. The results looks a bit random to me, but it looks like there is no significant difference between EditText and TextView. Only the Reflection method is slower:

```
try {
    String text = "";
    String result = "";

    //Reflection
    Long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
    View v = ctx.findViewById(R.id.hello_text);
    Field f = v.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mText");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    text = f.get(v).toString();
    time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() - time;                   
    result = "via Reflection ("+time.toString()+" ms)";

    //TextView
    time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
    TextView t = (TextView)ctx.findViewById(R.id.hello_text);
    text = t.getText().toString();
    time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() - time;
    result = result + "\nvia TextView ("+time.toString()+" ms)";

    //EditText
    time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
    EditText e = (EditText)ctx.findViewById(R.id.hello_text);
    text = e.getText().toString();
    time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() - time;                   
    result = result + "\nvia EditText ("+time.toString()+" ms)";

    Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
}
}
```

Comment: but you don't get the `getText()` method in `View`

Comment: well, you had to specify this. "I don't need anything specific to EditText" means to me that you just need the object. You didn't say "I need just the `.getText()` method".

Comment: yes.. I hear you.. and `getText` is not from the `EditText` class

Comment: here's a quick test (get the object and get the value of the text property), check it by yourself